# How can I create the directory equivalent of /dev/null?

Tags: folders, macos

I have some directories that fill up with useless items such as `~/Library/Application Scripts` or `~/Library/Caches` or others. There are `/dev/null` type inodes that discard anything written to them without returning any sort of error code, but these are for discarding bytes written to the file, not file/directories placed inside of a directory.

Is there a way to create an auto-emptying directory that deletes items placed inside the instant there are no more open file descriptors referencing them?

Simply placing *'block files'* of the same name in the location of the directories causes much software to break as the system calls return a failure code (either `EEXIST` or `ENOTDIR`) when they try to create a directory there.

Comment: Auto-deleting user Caches is a bad idea, and will cause problems, or at least performance issues. My user Application Scripts folder contains 656 items, but is 245 Kb on disk.

Comment: @benwiggy Those were just some quick examples.

Comment: I suppose you could create a [folder action](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/WatchFolders.html) which would delete files.

Comment: Without examples of directories where the contents actually are 'useless', this sounds like a solution without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution was to replace said directories with symbolic links to `~/.Trash`, so that said files would be deleted whenever I empty the trash.